# why the output is 2 and 0 for this program?

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting an unexpected output. please tell me y m getting dis?

code is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4};
    char *p;
    p = arr;
    p = (char*)((int*)(p));
    printf("%d, ", *p);
    p = (int*)(p+1);
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
  }
```

output:

> 2 0

Comment: In C, char is a single byte and int is 4 bytes (or, 2 bytes). Think about what you are doing. What you doing is very convoluted, probably because somebody specifically designed it that way to illustrate the point.

Comment: `p = (int*)(p+1);` Has undefined behaviour, think about the difference between `sizeof char` and `sizeof int`.

Comment: Please write English, n dis incomprhnzbl tn sp33k!

Comment: And @George is right here. What you get is very probably something meaningless because `p + 1` is not suitably aligned for int so the behaviour is undefined. Also you're not casting the pointer, so your program isn't valid C and your compiler must have output diagnostics that you should have copied into your question.

Answer (score 1):

How this `int arr[3] = {2, 3, 4}` statement will be stored in `memory` ? `arr` is  a **local variable** and it will be stored in **stack** section of RAM, assume starting address is `0x100`

```
 arr[0] arr[1] arr[2]
   |--------------------|
   |   2   |  3  |  4   |
   |--------------------|
  0x100     0x104  0x108
  arr 
  p
```

Next, `p = (char*)((int*)(p));` here first `p` converted into `int pointer` and later converted again into `char pointer`  i.e still `p` is pointing to `1st byte` only.

So when you are executing first `printf`

```
printf("%d, ", *p);
```

here `p` is `char pointer` and it will fetch what is the data in `0x100` to `0x101` which is `2` so it prints `2`

Next, when you are doing

```
p = (int*)(p+1); // here first p+1 will happen means 0x101 which is converted later into int pointer , but only in this statement(typecasting effect will be in this statement only  .
```

when you are printing next printf, `p` is still `char pointer` so it will fetch only `1 byte data` , not `4 byte`.

```
  printf("%d", *p);// it will print what is the data in 0x101 ? it's 0 check the binary representation of array
```

**test case**  :
if `p = (int*)(p+1)` could have putted inside `printf` then it yields different results, for e.g

```
printf("%d\n",(int*)(p+1))
```

I hope it helps.